# How to smooth in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, smoothing, loess

I'm trying to get a piece of MATLAB code to run in Octave, and I've come upon the line:

```
xsm = smooth(x,0.03,'loess')
```

which doesn't seem to have an octave equivalent. x is just an array of a few thousand real numbers.

Is there any Octave code out there which will do this for me, and if not, where do I find the algorithm so that I can write my own? And if I do that, how do I contribute it to Octave?

Comment: The documentation says ` sets the span of the moving average to span. span must be odd` about the second parameter, no idea what this is supposed to do. (http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html)

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia article yet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression

Comment: Daniel, this 'loess' is a more complicated type of smoothing than moving average. Ben, yes, I was just hoping someone would already have done it!

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden: You are right, this is the relevant part of the documentation: "For the loess and lowess methods, span is a percentage of the total number of data points, less than or equal to 1.", `0.03` is a valid parameter.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden Looks like someone has already implemented it: http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/data-smoothing/ci/584d6abf26660549ff38c6a8d5fec86d2c1cef8b/ or else maybe http://octave.sourceforge.net/data-smoothing/

Comment: @Dan, that's the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some loess code in Excel Basic, which might be a start:

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/loess-smoothing-in-excel/

Answer (score 3):

Looks like someone has already implemented it: [smooth.m](http://sourceforge.net/p/octave/data-smoothing/ci/584d6abf26660549ff38c6a8d5fec86d2c1cef8b/) or else maybe [data smoothing package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/data-smoothing/) on Octave-Forge

Comment: Actually, this file implements the moving-average and sgolay smoothing (so it's a start!), but the particular "loess" smooth that I'm trying to use isn't implemented yet.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden Then maybe you should un-accept the answer, see if someone can provide something better...

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden The [`data smoothing` package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/data-smoothing/) contains also [`regdatasmooth`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/data-smoothing/function/regdatasmooth.html) which is neither moving-average nor sgolay. It can perform very nicely. Just make sure to play with the "lambda" parameter. For instance `y_smooth = regdatasmooth(x_data, y_data, "lambda", lambda, "xhat", x_smooth)`